# Android native java8 support for API 16 4.1.2

Tags: android, android-studio, java-8

I'm currently building an app which has target and source compatibility set to java 1.8, compiledSdkVersion 27, targetSdkVersion 27 and minSdkVersion 16.

Whenever I run my app on newer devices, everything works just fine. But I recently got a hold of old crappy lg device (LG-E430) which has android 4.1.2 (API16) and if I try to run the app on it I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sample.app.-$$Lambda$Application$UEhM22H-x38DdLAimT-WuD_uUWc
```

From android documentation I see that lamdas are supported on all android versions. But exception says otherwise.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: You may want to show as to how you are using lambdas in your code. Possible that you found a bug: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#disable

Answer (score 0):

See You Have Build Virtual Device On Android Studio And Then Try To Run Your Project I think it will work. If It Still Not Works Then open `Build.gradle` and sync your project and then Run it then it will work